# Send string literal as argument in C++ template - Parameter pack

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

My function declaration and implementation. 
It accepts variable number of arguments

```
template <typename... ParamType,
            typename = typename std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<ParamType, std::string> ||
                                                            std::is_floating_point_v<ParamType> ||
                                                            std::is_integral_v<ParamType>>...>>
static inline void Log(const ParamType &... args)
{
   //Implementation
}
```

I need to add support for cstrings(char *, const char *) and string literals.

```
Console::Log("Non std::string literal"); //ERROR (const char [24])
Console::Log("hola %s %s %d %s"s,"helloWorld"s,"Joma"s,1, 1990); //OK
Console::Log<String, String, String,int, int>("hola %s %s %d %s"s,"helloWorld"s,"Joma"s,1, 1990); //OK
```

Comment: Just add `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<ParamType>, char const *>` etc. to the disjunction.

Comment: Error std::is_same_v<char [24], const char *> was not satisfied.

Comment: That's the "etc": you'd also need the same expression with `char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key expression is this disjunction:

```
std::is_same_v<ParamType, std::string> ||
std::is_floating_point_v<ParamType> ||
std::is_integral_v<ParamType>
```

You just need to add these terms:

```
std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<ParamType>, char const *> ||
std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<ParamType>, char *>
```

The usage of `std::decay_t` will cause the type of `"abc"` (which is `char const (&)[4]`) to decay to `char const *`.

Note that the function will receive string literal arguments as `char const (&)[N]` so the implementation needs to be able to handle that.